# Is new super.constructor a valid expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, specifications, super, referenceerror, new-expression

I would like to know if expressions of the form `new super.SomeProperty` are valid in JavaScript.

This question arose while working with code that behaves inconsistently across browsers like the example in the snippet below.

```js
class Test {
    test() {
        return new super.constructor;
    }
}

console.log((new Test).test());
```

This prints an empty object in Firefox and Edge but throws a `ReferenceError` in Chrome and a `SyntaxError` in Safari. The error can be easily circumvented putting parentheses around `super.constructor` or using a variable, so it's not a real limitation, rather a matter of curiosity about the language itself. I checked the spec but couldn't find anything implying that an error should be thrown in this case, so it's likely that I'm missing something.

Comment: Well [`class`es aren't supported by IE at all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Browser_compatibility). There are [many JS standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) these days with varying support (mainly ruined by IE). I'd advise using a precompiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) if you want to use ECMAScript 2015 defintions.

Comment: It's not clear for me if the dot in `new super.constructor`, which is defined in [superPropertyReference](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-makesuperpropertyreference), should have the same operator precendence as the member access operator [superPropertyReference](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-makesuperpropertyreference).

Comment: And I didn't find anything in the spec about how `super` should behave in the context of `new ...`. IMO. this is a case of unspecified behaviour

Answer (score 3):

According to MDN [Operator precedence article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) new without argument list is lower than member access. This suggests that `new super.constructor` should be evaluated as `new (super.constructor)` and Firefox and Edge are correct.

Now, according to the specs:

`new super.constructor` is **new** *NewExpression* (https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-new-operator). *NewExpression* is in form of *MemberExpression*, which is in form of *SuperProperty* which is in form of **super**.*IdentifierName*. ES6 standard seems to say the same. So it seems to me that MDN is correct, and so Firefox and Edge are compliant with the spec.

Comment: The whole answer turns around "NewExpression is in form of MemberExpression,". Can you precise the reference ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret Specification has links everywhere. I take https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-new-operator that the new operator should eat everything that qualifies as MemberExpression until it finds Arguments.

Comment: @AndrewSvietlichnyy that's also the result of operator precedence rules but the hole I couldn't fill is "Is super.constructor a MemberExpression?". That would make sense of course but I think the question is about specification.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Isn't `constructor` just a regular property name? Chrome parses `new super.constructor` as `(new super).constructor` and `new super` isn't valid syntax because `super` is neither NewEpxression nor MemberExpression.

Comment: No it isn't: look at this: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-makesuperpropertyreference

Comment: Chrome evaluates `return new (super.constructor)` just fine. `super.constructor` is just the same MemberExpression as `super.randomPropertyName` (https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-MemberExpression). Right, and Chrome doesn't raise a syntax error, so for some strange reason it doesn't resolve that reference.